# SendGrid, not a valid RFC-5321 address response

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Why does Gmail prevent me from sending emails via SendGrid? I've always done this and recently I'm being totally blocked.

The message I receive is as follows:

> The gmail.com server informed us that this message bounced. To protect your deliverability, we won't send to this address anymore.
>
> If you want to send to this address, you may remove it from the Bounces suppression group.

Full response from the gmail.com server:

> 553 5.1.2 The sender address `<bounces+6452016-d6d6-******=gmail.com@ 5.1.2 _mail.***.**>` is not a valid RFC-5321 address. z1-v6si718011qtz.4 - gsmtp

If anyone has any clue how to solve this, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you are sending emails using SendGrid to your Gmail inbox, then when you try to reply back the email you get the error?

Comment: No, Google blocks the delivery before it can be received.

Comment: How are you using SendGrid to send the email then?

Comment: The answer to the first part of your question is yes: he's using Sendgrid to send mails to his Gmail inbox. But Gmail is refusing them.

Comment: I've been intermittently experiencing the same issue over the last week. I think Gmail is correct in it's response, the address you listed is indeed not a valid email address (it contains spaces). This is exactly what we're seeing as well. I've reported the issue to SendGrid but haven't heard back yet. @PauloMendonça - Did you learn any more information about the issue?

Comment: not yet @joshb!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL; DR: this was probably a bug in Sendgrid's platform, which they appear to have fixed.

---

We also had the same issue, and raised a ticket with Sendgrid about it a few weeks ago.

After several rounds of back-and-forth we were sure that the issue was on their side - their system was adding spaces to the return-path which recipient servers like Google then rejected.

```
bounces+6452016-d6d6-******=gmail.com@ 5.1.2 _mail.***.**
                                      ^ invalid space here
```

In our case this only happened when there was *more than one recipient* specified for the email.

The Sendgrid support team were very helpful in digging into the issue, and they came back to us a few days ago to say that they have pushed a fix on their side. This seems to have resolved the issue for us and we're no longer seeing messages rejected for invalid return addresses.